# How to rename multiple pdfs in Powershell using itextsharp

Tags: powershell, itext

Im trying to rename every pdf file in a folder according to variables obtained from those files but i cant get it to work, i can rename one file at a time but i cant manage to make it work for every file.

Here is what i have to rename one file:

```
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\...\itextsharp.dll"

    $file = "C:\Program Files\...\pdf file.pdf"

    $pdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $file

    $text=[iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($pdf,1)

    $startss = $text.LastIndexOf("Completo")

    $endss = $text.LastIndexOf("Doc")

    $name = $text.Substring($startss +9,$endss - $startss-10)

    $startss2 = $text.LastIndexOf("Modalidad")

    $endss2 = $text.LastIndexOf("(Entre")

    $mode = $text.Substring($startss2 +10,$endss2 - $startss2-10)

    Rename-Item -NewName ($name + "-" + $mode + ".pdf") -Path "$file"

    $pdf.Close()
```

And here is what i have to rename every file:

```
    $folder = "C:\...\pdfs folder"

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\...\itextsharp.dll"

    $pdffiles = Get-ChildItem -File "$folder\*.pdf"

    Foreach($file in $pdffiles)
    {


    $pdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $file

    $text=[iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($pdf,1)

    $startss = $text.LastIndexOf("Completo")

    $endss = $text.LastIndexOf("Doc")
    
    $name = $text.Substring($startss +9,$endss - $startss-10)

    $startss2 = $text.LastIndexOf("Modalidad")

    $endss2 = $text.LastIndexOf("(Entre")

    $mode = $text.Substring($startss2 +10,$endss2 - $startss2-10)

    Rename-Item -NewName ($name + "-" + $mode + "-" + ".pdf") -Path "$file"

    $pdf.Close()
    }
```

Hope someone can help me to make it work, thanks in advance

Comment: How is it not working?  Please include any relevant output or errors.  One difference is that in your first snippet `$file` is a `[String]` whereas in the second `$file` is a `[System.IO.FileInfo]`.  In your `Foreach` loop try `$pdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $file.FullName` to pass the full file path to the `PdfReader` constructor.

Comment: Also, can you be absolutely sure all pdf files indeed contain the text fragments you use to get the `IndexOf()` from? If not found, IndexOf() returns -1

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include the error. I am 100% sure that all the files contain the text fragments. It worked when i added .FullName, it looks that that was it, thanks a lot Lance and Theo